# how to import "org.apache.http.client.HttpClient" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, apache

I have tried `httpcore.jar` by following the step [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/download.html), but when I write `import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`, it still can't be found.
The jar is already downloaded by Maven.

Is `httpcore` the right lib for importing `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`?
or `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` is just used for Android developing?

Another question, what is the difference between `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` and `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient`?

Answer (score 4):

First of all: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

> The Commons HttpClient project is now end of life, and is no longer
>   being developed. It has been replaced by the Apache HttpComponents
>   project in its HttpClient and HttpCore modules, which offer better
>   performance and more flexibility.

So, you need to use HttpClient (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), not Commons HttpClient (take a look in the name of the packages that you said).

Yes, org.apache.http.client.HttpClient is the right package.

Did you have certain that Maven obtained the .jar and it is in your classpath?

Comment: I've used the Groovy port of this Apache HttpClient lots of times and it's very easy and expressive to use (if you like Groovy): http://groovy.codehaus.org/HTTP+Builder

Comment: it's fixed now, by adding segments like :                        <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
 <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
 <version>4.0-alpha4</version>
</dependency>                                  also, setup in property. it works.