# Java Beginner Packages in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, dependencies, package

I am currently attempting to edit a larger java project. After reading suggestions for how to get started, I decided to attempt to build the project first to play around with some of the code and see if I could get an understanding for the hierarchy of the project.

Unfortunately, I can't even seem to get past some of the basic issues such as missing package imports, and I'm not sure what is the best way to fix them. I currently set up my project on IntelliJ to pull from my git repo, and some packages are missing and display an error like:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse; 
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
```

For each of these import statements, however, the http is underlined in red. I'm guessing this is a missing dependency? What would be the best way to resolve this?

build.sbt file:

```
import AssemblyKeys._

assemblySettings

organization := ""

name := "service"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

mainClass in assembly := Some("")

jarName in assembly :=  { s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar" }

val deployDevTask = TaskKey[Unit]("deploy-dev", "Copies assembly jar to a dev remote location")

val devNode = ""

deployDevTask <<= assembly map { (asm) =>
  val local = asm.getPath
  val remote = devNode + ":" + "/tmp/" + asm.getName
  println(s"Copying: $local -> $remote")
  Seq("scp", local, remote) !!
}
```

Comment: Does your Git repo include any jar files, or does it use a build system? If it uses maven/gradle as a build system you will see a file called "pom.xml" or "build.gradle"--is that the case for you?

Comment: No. So I understand to a very basic level what pom.xml and build.gradle are useful for, but my repo doesn't have either of those files. I think I have a build.sbt file, but I can't seem to make much sense out of it versus a pom.xml file

Comment: Does this happen to be a Scala project? `build.sbt` is used to control the scala build tool, which downloads dependencies and then uses them and your source code to build your project. You might need to install an IntelliJ/IDEA plugin in order to build using that buildfile.

Comment: It is a Scala project -- I guess I am a little lost on why a lot of the imports are successful while some fail. I am working with a slightly older project, so is it possible that some of the dependencies no longer exist which is why when I build this project I am no longer able to find them? I found this link and wasn't sure if this was relative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710191/how-to-import-org-apache-http-client-httpclient-in-eclipse

Comment: It might help if you posted at least the dependencies section of build.sbt in your post as an edit.

Comment: OK, it looks like there are no dependency entries in the Jar as far as I can tell. It means that you will probably need to fetch the jars manually and add them (although I have no experience with SBT or Scala, so I'm averse to posting a final answer)

Comment: Not a problem, sorry I couldn't give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" %% "httpclient" % "4.5"
```

Then hover the icon at the bottom-left of IntelliJ IDEA which should bring up a list of different views - select `SBT`.  (If you don't see `SBT`, go into preferences and add it as a plugin.)

In the `SBT` view, click the "Refresh" icon (it's the first icon).  Watch it downloads the dependencies.  It'll popup a message if it can't download the dependency.

Finally the red underscores should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer at the time of writing is to add the line stated by bjfletcher, but with a *single* % rather than double:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5"
```

From the sbt docs http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Library-Dependencies.html, when using double percentages (%%) sbt will add your project’s Scala version to the artifact name. Often this isn't what you want as a build from a slightly different Scala version will be compatible and there may not be an exact version match available.

Using the single percentage means that you'll get a version even if there isn't an exact match with your Scala version.